# Microwave injection into cavity, approximately 2.4GHz

Tags: antenna, microwave

I need to inject a few Watts of microwave radiation transversely into a pipe. Since I have no microwave expertise I would like some general advice.

My naïve expectation is to somehow couple the radiation into a waveguide of some kind and plumb it into one side of the pipe. A much less ideal solution would be to have a WiFi style antenna inside the pipe.

Power levels would be in the 10W range, or possible higher. I would also like to tune the wavelength to match the pipe diameter to form a resonant cavity, but that's fairly straightforward electronics.

Comment: I've done the "WiFi in a pipe" thing - fun project :P. The pipe was actually a steel-braided air hose and it was mostly under water. It was very lossy ...

Answer (score 0):

The basic information appears to be [shown in this diagram](https://workforce.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electronics_Technology/Book%3A_Electric_Circuits_II_-_Alternating_Current_%28Kuphaldt%29/14%3A_Transmission_Lines/14.08%3A_Waveguides):
[image]

> Signals are typically introduced to and extracted from waveguides by
> means of small antenna-like coupling devices inserted into the
> waveguide. Sometimes these coupling elements take the form of a
> dipole, which is nothing more than two open-ended stub wires of
> appropriate length. Other times, the coupler is a single stub (a
> half-dipole, similar in principle to a “whip” antenna, 1/4λ in
> physical length), or a short loop of wire terminated on the inside
> surface of the waveguide